# Extracting data, starting 12 month back....onwards

Tags: sql, oracle

Joining two tables A and B on account_id. Trying to retrieve data from balance column from table B. The thing is that I need to fetch the first balance amount that would be found starting at -12 from the date today (example: '01SEP2019'). If not found at -12, look at -11, then -10....and so on. The thing is that for some account_id, balance can be found at -12, so others at -6 and so on. Thanks

Tried using the `add_months function = ('01SEP2019',-12)`, but got

> "invalid number of arguments"

```
select account_id, balance
from table_A a
left join table_B b
    on (a.acc = b.acc)
where a.month_end_date = '01SEP2019'
  and b.month_end_date = add_months('01SEP2019'-12)
```

Comment: Which data type do the month_end_date columns have?

Comment: You could use the DATE_ADD funtion from version 4 onwards

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and the correct database tag would all help.  MySQL does not have an `add_months()` function, so it should be returning an unknown function error.

Comment: month_end_date columns have DATE data type

Comment: Basically I am trying to get the first balance found, starting at T-12 months. If its not found at T-12, check at T-11 months. If not found, check at T-10 months and so on.....until balance is found.

Answer (score -1):

You give date strings as `'01SEP2019'` and so forth.  That's not a usable date string format. Try `'2019-09-01'` instead. And, use `DATE` (or `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`) data types to store dates, not text strings.

If you want a date twelve months before your given date try this date arithmetic expression.

```
... AND col = '2019-09-01' - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
```

As you have discovered, `ADD_MONTHS()` is [an Oracle thing, not a MySQL thing](http://oracletomysqlmigration.openthinklabs.com/home/functions/add_months).

Comment: Thanks, i will try that. The thing is that I wasn't clear on the tags, as i am new to this. I am using Toad for Oracle, but thought that Sql is the same between Oracle and MySQL. Thanks for clarification, will keep an eye on that.

Comment: String `'2019-09-01'` is as bad as the other one. Use literals (e.g. `DATE '2019-09-01'`or `TIMESTAMP '2019-09-01 00:00:00'`) or function `TO_DATE` with format identifier. Interval literal would be `INTERVAL '12' MONTH`